# How do I breed without evolving my Pokemon?

Tags: pokemon-series

I recently got a Skitty from a friend and I want to breed it so I can have more. I read that if I put it with a Ditto that it should breed with my Skitty... the only issue is I don't want my Skitty to evolve into a Delcatty. How can I let my Skitty breed without fear of it evolving?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Fortunately, you [don't have to worry](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Pok%C3%A9mon_Day_Care) about your Skitty evolving because:

> Pokémon will not evolve while in Day Care, even if they meet the requirements to.

Comment: And because Skitty needs a Moon Stone to evolve, so even if Pokémon could evolve by level up in the Day Care, Skitty couldn't.

Comment: Even with (Skitty.getMoonStone() = false && Skitty.inDayCare() = true) stopping it from evolving, you could always give it the hold item Everstone to prevent it from evolving once more.

It would then be the most prevented-from-evolving Pokemon ever.

Comment: @pandorym it may be required! `false * false = true`? My head hurts.